# Do HTML hidden input fields have a location?

Tags: html, hidden-field

Do hidden input fields have a physical location within the page?

I know this question probably sounds dumb (I definitely feel like it for asking), but recently I created a website with a lot of hidden fields (created with JavaScript DOM), and I noticed there is a huge, empty area at the bottom of the page.

I checked the code and I can't find anything that could cause this problem.

```
var hiddenfield = document.createElement('input');
hiddenfield.setAttribute("type","hidden");
hiddenfield.name = "hiddenfield";
hiddenfield.id = "hiddenfield";
hiddenfield.setAttribute("value", document.getElementById("select1 4").value);
formNew.appendChild(hiddenfield);
```

I edited in some code to show the way I created the hidden fields.

Comment: Can you show us some html code ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, `input type="hidden"` fields aren't causing this. Possibly some css style or `width` and `height` settings.

They *do* have a location, try to change `hidden` in `text` from the developer console and you will see it's position. They are just collapsed. The don't influence layout in any way.

Comment: He might be using `visibility:hidden`. In that case shouldn't it take some space? as in [W3](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp)

`"visibility:hidden hides an element, but it will still take up the same space as before. The element will be hidden, but still affect the layout."`

Comment: `input type="hidden"` renders to nothing, so it isn't necessary.

Comment: +1. Thank you for clarification. Learned a new thing :)

Comment: @Pye: true, but the question is about `input type="hidden"`. See the [tag:hidden-field] tag.

Comment: @PatrickHofman I assume that *SyedAliTaqi* were talking about `visibilty:hidden` on something else than `<input type="hidden" />`

Comment: @Pye: I guess so, but that wasn't the question.

Comment: @PatrickHofman All we can do is assuming since we don't know how "hidden fields created with JavaSscript DOM" looks like

Comment: @Pye: The tag is specifically for `input type="hidden"`. If it isn't about it, the question was tagged badly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I now go through the code to find the cause of the problem. At least I know it's not the hidden fields.

Comment: @benedekadam: You're welcome. There is a little confusion about your question, whether you really mean `input type="hidden"`. Can you confirm that. Else check [Syed's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25931191/993547).

Comment: @PatrickHofman Yes, I mean `input type = "hidden"`. I included an example field in my original question.

Comment: @benedekadam: Okay. Thanks. That clears the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `<input type="hidden">` then as *Patrick* answered they will not influence layout. As in **[this](http://jsfiddle.net/4vst8vto/)** example explained by *Patrick*.

**BUT** if you are hiding your `input fields` using `visibility:hidden` then **YES** it will take the space. See **[THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/4vst8vto/2/)** example.

As according to **[W3](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp)**

> "visibility:hidden hides an element, but it will still take up the same space as before. The element will be hidden, but still affect the layout."

You can hide your `fields` using `display:none`. According to W3

> display:none hides an element, and it will not take up any space. The element will be hidden, and the page will be displayed as if the element is not there